# Remove line break in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller

My `UIActivityViewController` presents an image with some text underneath it:

```
let objectsToShare: [AnyObject] = [anImage, someText]
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
```

It's adding an undesired line break in between the image and the text when shared (red highlight):

[image: unwanted UIActivityViewController line break]

Is there a way to remove it? FYI `someText` does not have any hard-coded line breaks in it. I'm impartial to an Objective-C or Swift answer to this.

Comment: It looks like it just a way how Apple thinks it is right and most likely it isn't possible to change this behaviour. Anyway good luck finding an answer or workaround!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark. Have you tried a negative Y position value for "someText". I know its a bit hacky, but it might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not really in control of rendering the activities, only supplying them, you don't have control over the padding that is placed between the content and the activities.

I would explain to my designer/client/boss that it's out of your control, unfortunately, and file a rdar if you really think this is something you should have control of (I don't think it is, personally).

**Hacky and not at all recommended...**
Since UIActivityViewController is a UIViewController, you could, I guess, subclass it and iterate through the subviews in the .view of that object to find the right view/constraint and adjust it yourself but this is truly not something I would go near even if my job depended on it. It assumes so much about how Apple implemented that views hierarchy that you are a hostage to fortune that it will fail in any future iOS update where Apple may decided to rework that class.